# getline(cin,str) skips first input if not added cin.ignore but after adding it skips first character

Tags: c++

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    string sen;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,sen);
    cout<<" \n sen -> "<<sen<<endl;
}
```

this is my code.

Problem : when not adding `cin.ignore()`, `getline(cin,sen)` skips first input but after adding the `cin.ignore()`, after first input , the first character of every input it missing.

I viewed many post in stack overflow but didn't found the solution.

Input :

```
<tag1 value = "HelloWorld">
<tag2 name = "Name1">
</tag2>
</tag1>
```

output of current code :

```
 sen -> <tag1 value = "HelloWorld">

 sen -> tag2 name = "Name1">

 sen -> /tag2>

 sen -> /tag1>
```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe.  move `cin.ignore();` t be after the last `cin >> ...` before the loop.

Comment: it worked, thank you for the solution.

Comment: but just as a point, this question is not a possible duplicate of what you have marked because in that example the whole input of getline was not extracted.